# Open a terminal window to a specified folder from a Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, terminal

I have seen this thread on how to execute terminal commands from within a Cocoa app. But I want to actually launch Terminal.app to a specified directory.

I know that the following does not work:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:folderPath withApplication:@"Terminal"];
```

Terminal tries to actually open the folder as a file.

Is this something I have to use AppleScript for?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use AppleScript from Cocoa like this:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd %@\"", folderPath];

NSAppleScript *as = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: s];
[as executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

AppleScript script was taken from cobbal. Thanks mate!

Comment: Although perhaps overkill for this use, the Scripting Bridge (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good solution for communicating with external apps via AppleScript from within Objective-C apps.

Comment: be careful of folders with a quotation marks or spaces in them though

Comment: Is there any way to not showing the Terminal App? Can Scripting Bridge achieve this behaviour?

Comment: The folder path must be quoted like this or this command won't work correctly: `@"tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd \\\"%@\\\"\""`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a way to do it in plain cocoa, but in applescript it's fairly trivial

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd ~/Desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers suggesting using the `cd` command are great. Additionally, I recommend checking out the source to the app [cdto](http://code.google.com/p/cdto/) for a great example. Cdto is a fast mini application that opens a Terminal.app window cd'd to the front most finder window. This app is designed (including it's icon) to placed in the finder window's toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (now obsolete) AppleEvent Carbon API to send an "Do Script" event to Terminal.app :

```
OSStatus doTerminalScript (NSString* script) {
    AppleEvent evt;
    OSStatus err;
        // Build event
    err = AEBuildAppleEvent(kAECoreSuite, kAEDoScript, 
                            typeApplicationBundleID, "com.apple.terminal", 18L,
                            kAutoGenerateReturnID, kAnyTransactionID, &evt, NULL,
                            "'----':utf8(@)", strlen([script UTF8String]), [script UTF8String]);
    if (err) return err;
    AppleEvent res;
        // Send event
    err = AESendMessage(&evt, &res, kAEWaitReply, kAEDefaultTimeout);
    AEDisposeDesc(&evt);
    if (err) return err;
        // Check for any errors from Terminal.app
    AEDesc desc;
    err = AEGetParamDesc(&res, keyErrorNumber, typeSInt32, &desc);
    AEDisposeDesc(&res);
    if (!err) {
        AEGetDescData(&desc, &err, sizeof(err));
        AEDisposeDesc(&desc);
    } else if (err == errAEDescNotFound)
        err = noErr;
    return err;
}
```

Taken form [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/196568-using-terminal-within-cocoa-app.html#196579).
Note that Terminal.app must be launched with `-[NSWorkspace launchApplication:]` if not running.
If wanted, it can be put in foreground with `- [NSApplication activateWithOptions:]`

As suggested by a comment, this can be easily ported to the more modern [Scripting Bridge API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/AboutScriptingBridge/AboutScriptingBridge.html).

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know AppleScript, but I bet you could use it for this.

If the terminal directory is the same each time, you could just make an executeable .sh file with a `cd` command in it and make that the openFile argument.