# Open Terminal window from mac app and perform script

Tags: swift, bash, macos, shell, terminal

Hi I want to write an app that includes a few buttons for scripts I use daily.
I want to click a button and Terminal to open with a script (or multiple scripts) running, like:

```
let scripts = [
    "cd ~/Documents/Websites/someApp/",
    "ng serve --port 4300 -o"
]
performInTerminal(scripts)
```

I know how to...
**Open Terminal:**

```
private func openTerminal(){
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app", isDirectory: true) as URL
    let path = "/bin"
    let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
    configuration.arguments = [path]
    NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url, configuration: configuration, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

and how to ... **Perform a Script:**

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with anything other than `ls` and it has no connection to the terminal window, which makes sense.

```
private func performScript(_ args: String...){
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    process.arguments = args
    process.launch()
    process.waitUntilExit()
}
```

Any ideas on how to merge those two?

***UPDATE***

I now added the function using Apple Script:

```
private func performInTerminal(_ scripts:[String]){
    let concatScript = scripts.joined(separator: "; ")
    let source = """
    tell application "Terminal"
        if not (exists window 1) then reopen
        activate
        do script "\(concatScript)"
    end tell
    """
    let appleScript = NSAppleScript(source: source)
    var possibleError: NSDictionary?
    appleScript?.executeAndReturnError(&possibleError)
    if let error = possibleError {
        for key in error.allKeys{
            if let key = key as? String{
                print("\(key): \(error.value(forKey: key)!)")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Problem now are Entitlements:
With the following in `AppName.entitlements` it works, but It requests permissions every time:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.Terminal</string>
</array>
```

With the following I get `-10004: Terminal got an error: A privilege violation occurred.`:

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
     <key>com.apple.Terminal</key>
     <array>
          <string>*</string>
     </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014600/how-to-execute-terminal-command-in-swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a terminal window to a specified folder from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446814/open-a-terminal-window-to-a-specified-folder-from-a-cocoa-app)

Comment: @Sweeper this doesn't open the Terminal app. It is "basically" the same as the performing a script from a mac app section in my question, just with an external script.

Comment: @Willeke, Ahh nice Apple Script  thanks for the hint. Will try

Comment: @Willeke I used the post you suggested and updated my question

Comment: I believe the solution is to set com.apple.security.scripting-targets properly. Did you managed to find out how?