# How to pass arguments to mac terminal in llldb mode

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, lldb

I'am developing an mac app.I need to open the terminal and execute `lldb` command. I've found the solution:[Open a terminal window to a specified folder from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446814/open-a-terminal-window-to-a-specified-folder-from-a-cocoa-app). However，i need to pass more arguments to the opened terminal after entering `lldb` mode. so i'm confused about there is any way that my app can communication with the terminal?

for example:

Firstly, i open a terminal and enter in `lldb` mode.

```
NSAppleScript *as = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: @"tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"lldb\""];
NSDictionary *errors = nil;
[as executeAndReturnError:&errors];
if (errors) {
    NSLog(@"start lldb error: %@", errors);
}
```

Then i want to pass `lldb` command to the opened terminal, like `process connect connect://xxxx`. But i can't find any way to make it.

Comment: Not sure why you have tagged [ios], but for macOS [one of these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-a-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild) will probably help.

Comment: because i need use lldb to connect remote ios device. i want to pass some `lldb` command to the terminal, like `process connect connect://xxx`.

Comment: Are you actually using the fact that lldb is running in a Terminal session?  If not, it would probably be easier to use NSTask and write & read to the input & output handles that affords.

Comment: yep, my thoughts is pass some lldb command from my app. Then execute lldb command in the terminal. But, i can't find any to to communicate between my app and the terminal. By the way, NSTask can perform lldb command? Are there any relative examples?